# Issue regarding the callback url on vimeo

Tags: callbackurl, vimeo-api

what would be a callback url of any iphone app on vimeo. Vimeo is not redirect me to the app after authorizing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the coolest features of the iPhone SDK is an application’s ability to “bind” itself to a custom URL scheme and for that scheme to be used to launch itself from either a browser or from another application on the iPhone. chech [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) for more.